# How to highlight a cell based on another cells value VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

This question has been asked before but I went about doing it another way. I am trying to highlight a cell if it is greater than the value of another cell.

Here is my code:

```
Sub Error_Search()

Dim Summary As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long
Set Summary = Worksheets("Summary")


            lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 20).End(xlUp).Row

    With Summary

            For i = lr To 3 Step -1

            If Range("L" & i).Value > Range("$Q$2:$R$3").Value Then Range("L" & i).Font.Color = -16776961

            Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Range("$Q$2:$R$3") is a merged cell and it is the cell I want to compare the cell I want to highlight to.

I keep getting a mismatch error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

G

Comment: What happens if you compare to Range("$Q$2") ? - top left so to speak

Comment: ^^^ the issue is with merged cells, the value is stored in the upper-left cell.  all the others are blank.  So when you try `Range("L" & i).Value > Range("$Q$2:$R$3").Value` you are trying to exercise logical operators between one cell and a variant array of 4, and Excel does not like that.  so just use the upper-left cell of the merged cells.

Comment: Second question today involving code that should have never been written in the first place. This is a job for conditional formatting, not VBA code.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the problem is that a multiple-cells `Range` doesn't have a single `Value`, even if the cells are merged: `Range.Value` yields a 2D variant array whenever more than a single cell is involved. So you can fix the bug by only referring to the top-left cell of the merged range instead.

That said...

You don't need any VBA code to do this; conditional formatting handles it quite neatly.

[image: Conditional format formula: =$C4>$M$3]

> ```
>  =$C4>$M$3
> ```

Note the $ dollar signs: `$M$3` would be your merged cell (only the leftmost cell matters), and `$C4` is just the first cell you're defining the conditional format into; leaving the row non-absolute (i.e. no $ on the row number) allows you to apply the format to an entire range of cells by specifying the *Applies to* range:

[image: cells in $D:$L where $C is greater than $M$3 are highlighted]

Note that the format formula is the same regardless of whether we're looking at $M$3 or $M$3:$N$3 merged cells.

Conditional formats will perform much better than any VBA code you can write.